# libgit2 pathspec match single folder non recursive

Tags: git, glob, libgit2

With git I can use glob style pathspec patterns to match a single folder without its subdirectories:

```
git status ':(glob)*'           // matches root but no subdirectories
git status ':(glob)myFolder/*'  // matches myFolder but no subdirectories
```

I am trying to achieve something similar using libgit2. However, calling `git_status_list_new` does not work as expected. I do *not* set `GIT_STATUS_OPT_DISABLE_PATHSPEC_MATCH` on the status options. I do pass the pathspec as I would pass it to gits CLI, e.g. `:(glob)myFolder/*`
.
Looking through the code of libgit2 reveals code that is intended to match glob patterns. I don't see any other options on the `git_status_options` that would enable this pattern to match. Is there any other way to match only a single folder non recursive without passing all files individually?

Comment: `:(glob)` is git command-line magic to tell it to interpret the pattern as a glob.  Have you tried just using `*` and `myFolder/*`?  What's the results of that?

Comment: `*` computes the status of the entire repository and `myFolder/*` does so for the directory  plus all the subdirectories, so it is recursive. The glob syntax limits the status to the directory in a non recursive way

Comment: Aha, yes, I understand.  This is not currently supported but would make a nice addition to the library.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll open an issue on GitHub